# Count the number of faces using dlib's facial landmark detector using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Basically the code I'm writing needs to add a string in front of values being calculated every frame

For example:

**Face 1: (eye aspect ratio), (mouth aspect ratio)**

**Face 2: (eye //  //), (// // //)**

... and so on, depending on how many faces are found using dlib's predictor.

The String needed here is **"Face1: "** |||| **"Face2: "** ... the other values are already found

Here's the code:

```
# Start capturing WebCam
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
framecount = 0

while True:
     ret, frame = cap.read()
     framecount += 1
     frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 1500)

     if ret:
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         rects = detector(gray, 0)

         for rect in rects:
             x = rect.left()
             y = rect.top()
             x1 = rect.right() - x
             y1 = rect.bottom() - y

             landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(frame, rect).parts()])

             left_eye = landmarks[LEFT_EYE_POINTS]
             right_eye = landmarks[RIGHT_EYE_POINTS]

             inner_mouth = landmarks[MOUTH_INNER_POINTS]
             outer_mouth = landmarks[MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS]

             left_eye_hull = cv2.convexHull(left_eye)
             right_eye_hull = cv2.convexHull(right_eye)
             inner_mouth_hull = cv2.convexHull(inner_mouth)
             outer_mouth_hull = cv2.convexHull(outer_mouth)

             # drawing the contours on frame
             cv2.drawContours(frame, [left_eye_hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
             cv2.drawContours(frame, [right_eye_hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

             # Eye aspect ratio and Mouth aspect ratio
             ear_left = eye_aspect_ratio(left_eye)
             ear_right = eye_aspect_ratio(right_eye)
             MAR = mouth_aspect_ratio(inner_mouth)

             ## This part below:
             print(framecount," {:.2f}".format(ear_left), " {:.2f}".format(MAR))


             print("Number of faces: ", len(rects))
```

The first print function will print out the frame of video and display the Eye aspect ratio and Mouth aspect ratio. And if there is more than one face, it will repeat the frame number more than once but will have different values.

So, it does what I need it to do, however I want to add a name before each of these values.

Second print function displays the number of faces present in a video, in my case its number 3 for three faces.

Example of output:

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136mJ.png)

Example of output with Enumerate:

[Output example enum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0xj2.png)

Comment: I don't get your question. What are the names that you want to add and where do you want to add them? And why is `print("Number of faces: ", len(rects))` inside the the `for rect in rects:` loop? It prints out the number of faces several times. Is this intentional?

Comment: You can  address the numbering with `for i, rect in enumerate(rects): ....print("Face ", str(i), " has the following values:", val1, val2, val3) `. But will your detector always assign the faces in the same order? What if people move around?

Comment: @Piinthesky I just left the Number of faces in the loop to test it out, i don't need to actually get the number of faces.

Comment: @Piinthesky   I just need the end result to be something like this:
Face 1: frame, EAR, MAR

Comment: @Piinthesky  Thats a good question, but i actually don't know if their values switch as a person switches their position in front of the camera. i have to test that. thanks for that

Comment: @Piinthesky I tried the enumerate method you mentioned, the values are identical for face 1, face 2, face 3... meaning that It prints the same values 3 times then changes and is applied to the next 3 identical values

Comment: Since you didn't explain it, I assumed, each `rect` in `rects` represent one face and your loop iterates ove these values. Seemingly this is not the case.